# How I can turn a card that has different content on the front and back side

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

Hello I am trying to program with CSS a card that rotates when clicked and the content changes during the rotation.
However, the content changes after the rotation. How can I change the content during the rotation.

I tried to rotate the map to 90 degrees, change the content and then rotate back from 90 to 0 degrees. But I don't know how to do it.

Here is the code

```
    const [isCardTurned, setIsCardTurned] = useState(false)
    const animationInterval = useRef();
    const cardContainerRef = useRef();

  function turnCard(e) {

        cardContainerRef.current.style.transition = "1s";
        cardContainerRef.current.style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";
        animationInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
            setIsCardTurned((prevState) => { return !prevState })
        }, 1000);
    

    }


    useEffect(() => {
        cardContainerRef.current.style.transition = "1s";
        cardContainerRef.current.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
        clearInterval(animationInterval.current)

    }, [isCardTurned])

    return (
        <>
            {isCardTurned == false &&
                <>
                    <div className="cardContainer" onClick={turnCard} ref={cardContainerRef}>
                        <CardHead srcHead={props.srcHead} projektTitel={props.projektTitel} datumBegin={props.datumBegin} datumEnd={props.datumEnd} />
                        <div className="cardContent" >
                            <div className="cardImage">
                                <img src={props.imageSrc} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="cardShortDescription">
                                <div className="shortDescriptionText">
                                    {props.shortDescription}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            }
            {isCardTurned == true &&
                <>
                    <div className="cardContainer" onClick={turnCard} ref={cardContainerRef}>
                        <CardHead srcHead={props.srcHead} projektTitel={props.projektTitel} datumBegin={props.datumBegin} datumEnd={props.datumEnd} />
                        <div className="cardLongDescription">
                            <div className="cardLongDescriptionText">
                                {props.longDescription}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            }
        </>
    )
```

```
.cardContainer {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(199, 220, 248);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.cardContainer:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgb(5, 48, 112);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You code is inclonplete, where is `cardContainerRef` defined?

Comment: I have added to the posted code

Answer (score 0):

All right I have the solution. I know that it works, but I can't justify it 100%, because I don't deal with the frontend for a long time

The card changes only its content and not the whole container. For this reason, the container must be rendered 1x and the content every time the card turns.

As a solution, I have adjusted the render condition that you can see in the following code

```
    return (
        <>
            <div className="cardContainer" onClick={turnCard} ref={cardContainerRef}>
                <CardHead srcHead={props.srcHead} projektTitel={props.projektTitel} datumBegin={props.datumBegin} datumEnd={props.datumEnd} />
                <div className="cardContent" >
                    {isCardTurned == false &&
                        <>
                            <div className="cardImage">
                                <img src={props.imageSrc} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="cardShortDescription">
                                <div className="shortDescriptionText">
                                    {props.shortDescription}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    }
                    {isCardTurned == true &&
                        <>
                            <div className="cardLongDescription">
                                <div className="cardLongDescriptionText">
                                    {props.longDescription}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```